# Convert Short Zulu format date to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate

I am having troubles converting a short Zulu date format to a NSDate Object. I have found some answers for converting Zulu strings but mine looks like:

```
20111210T1000
```

And based on my researches, I am trying to do:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss Z"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@" +0000"]];
[f release];
```

I've tried many ways but my date is still nil...

How should I set my NSDateFormatter?

Comment: If the question is for OS X instead of iOS, replace the iOS tag with cocoa.

Comment: you are losing the DST offset by doing +0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick fix, in your date string you miss the timezone in the format, you should append (Paris one here) to your string and it should work. Also the format was wrong.

```
 NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'SSSZ"];
 NSString* str = @"20111210T1000-0100";   // NOTE -0100, GMT +1 Paris zone
 NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:str];
 NSLog(@"%@", date);
```